# How do you configure rolling logs with wildfly

Tags: wildfly

We are using wildfly and in our wildflyhome/standalone/log directory it's filling up with logs and eventually running out of disc space.  I would like to set up rolling logs and know that it's possible but just don't know how to do it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on linux just setup a cron job to purge the files.

If you want to use a size rotation that will only keep as many rotations as you tell it you can use a `size-rotating-file-handler`.

The following CLI command will replace the default `periodic-rotating-file-handler` with a `size-rotating-file-handler` which rotates when the log file reaches 50MB and will only keep 10 rotations.

```
batch 
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=FILE)
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:remove
/subsystem=logging/size-rotating-file-handler=FILE:add(append=true, autoflush=true, named-formatter=PATTERN, max-backup-index=10, rotate-size=50m, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path=server.log})
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=FILE)
run-batch
```